# How do I use redirect_to if I've got multiple controllers in different subdirectories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a small application to learn RoR. (Book database) It consists of a read-only area and a read-write admin area.

After I've got the admin functionality working first, I've moved the controller into a subdirectory and created the read-only controller.

Now when I'm updating a book in the admin area, the `redirect_to` function redirects to the read-only area.

What am I missing?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
class Admin::BooksController < ApplicationController
  <snip>
  def update
    @book = Book.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update_attributes params[:book]
        flash[:notice] = "Book updated"
        format.html { redirect_to @book }
        format.xml { head :ok }
      else
        <snip>
      end
    end
  end
  <snip>
end
```

This update itself works but it redirects me to `/books/1`, but I'd want it to redirect to `/admin/books/1`. I could just hardcode the correct path, but I guess that's not very good style.

What would be the proper way?

PS: Please comment if you need further information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are telling it to redirect to book because you are using rails' built in magical recognition of what it should do with the @book object (which is build a url to show the book using the book controller.

```
format.html { redirect_to @book }
```

If you want it to go elsewhere you need to be explicit about where you want it to go using a hash for [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000624)

```
format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'admin/book', :action => 'show', :id => @book   }
```

or use the paths like klew points out.

so for more detail -

`redirect_to (@book)`  or

```
redirect_to  book_path(@book)
```

are both shortcuts for this:

`redirect_to :controller => book, :action => 'show', :id => @book.id`

Comment: You are saying "using the book controller". But why is the 'other' book controller chosen? Can I control somehow which controller is preferred?

Comment: Probably redirect_to @book looks on object @book (not on the controller you are in) and try to find default controller - that's why you are redirected outside the admin namespace.

Comment: When you say redirect to @book rails' internal code converts that to the book controller and the default action for a single book object (show).  It's a nice syntactic sugar shortcut but it unfortunately also hides what is going on from newbies.

Answer (score 3):

Rails creates for you url helpers based on your routes.rb. If you have namespace then you can use this:

```
admin_book_path(@book)        # admin/books/2
admin_books_path              # admin/books
edit_admin_book_path(@book)   # admin/books/2/edit
```

and so on.

The other way is to use [resource_controller](http://github.com/giraffesoft/resource_controller/tree/master) it creates for you controller automaticaly and provides some ways to modify it if it's needed. It also gives you some useful url helpers

```
collection_path               # admin/books
object_path                   # admin/books/2
```

When you use above helpers in views, than it generates url with namespace if you are in one, or without namespace otherwise.

resource_controller isn't perfect, but in most cases it works good and saves a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass an array to redirect where the first element is a symbol representing the namespace, and the second the element the object.

```
redirect_to [:admin_book, @book]
```

You can also use this for form_for, link_to and any other helpers that require a path.

Comment: I tested it and I changed the code, so that it actually works and removed "I think".